# Wordpress Footer not displaying even after footer.php file is run

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my wordpress project footer is not displaying in all pages. Footer.php file is running I can debug, but the wp_footer() is not displaying the footer.

**footer.php**

```
<?php wp_footer();?> // here footer is not displayin, below code is running
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In local the footer is displaying perfect with the same code, but in live the footer is not displaying.

Comment: are you getting any error msg

Comment: no I am not getting any error

Comment: Because it is displaying in some pages then check that you haven't got unclosed div on the page(s) that it is not showing.

Comment: I have checked no any unclose tag are there, and the thing is that it is working in local, only in live footer is not displaying in any page

Comment: Did you check error.log file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are `missing wp_footer()` function in `index` and `page.php` file.
Please have a look folder structure in theme and identify the main page and content page and put `wp_footer()` function.

It will definitely help you.

Comment: No sir, I used <?php get_footer();?> in both files index.php and page.php

Comment: I debug the footer.php of theme folder that code is runnig but footer not displaying

Comment: What is theme are you using now. Please try to switch another theme and have a look whats happend.

Comment: IN other theme footer is displaying